# htaccess ignoring RewriteRule following new RewriteCond & RewriteRule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The below code works to rewrite page.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^pages/(.+)$   /page.php?page=$1 [L]
```

The when adding the below bit the new redirect works but the rewrite of page.php stops.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.fr [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.fr/fr/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteRule   ^pages/(.+)$   /page.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Can any explain why and how to fix the page.php rewrite stops working when that code has not changed, I have only added the new redirect but that works.

Comment: Wouldn't the incoming path be `/fr/pages/…` after the redirect?

Comment: Does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: What happens when you type the url without www?

Comment: Same behaviour as I have the rewrite for the non www. version as well

Comment: @user2234135 `input /pages/25` after 1st rule `/fr/pages/25`. So 2nd Rule doesn't  consider it as matched

Comment: You first rule is wrong. What is the purpose of that rule and adding `/fr/`?